# Unable to use SIM TOOL KIT on HTC

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I have a dealer's card where I can Recharge for Customer using Sim tool kit. But when I inserted my Sim card in HTC, I am unable to use the SIM TOOL Facility and unable to recharge. I have to change my handset and recharge for customer.

Could anyone please tell me how I would be able to use in HTC?

Regards

Comment: Which HTC is it exactly? Is it modified? Does the phone have SIM TOOL KIT in the app drawer or is there nothing in place of it? Please provide more details.

Comment: What is a dealer's card?